# Get Facebook Picture in Cocos2d-iphone V3

Tags: software-engineering, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d, facebook

I'm trying to get the profile picture from Facebook, but I'm getting the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImage stringByStandardizingPath]:
```

This is my code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=square", userid]];
 NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
 UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
 //convert UIImage to CCSprite
 CCTexture *texture = [CCTexture textureWithFile:image];
 CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:texture];
 sprite.position = ccp(winWidth*.5, winHeight*.5);
```

The error occurs in the UIImage *image line.

Comment: The error looks odd, but nevertheless you should check `data` for nil before passing it to `UIImage`, in case `dataWithContentsOfURL` has failed.

Answer (score 1):

That error occurs on this line:

```
CCTexture *texture = [CCTexture textureWithFile:image];
```

And this is the right way to do this:

```
CCTexture *texture = [[CCTexture alloc] initWithCGImage:image.CGImage
                                                   contentScale:image.scale];
```